# If I add several scopes in a single concern, how can I include them later separately where I need them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

for example:

```
module Concern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    scope :by_name, ->(name) { where('LOWER(name) like ?', "%#{ name.downcase }%") }
  end

  included do
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: You cannot include parts of a module. If you want to include the scopes separately, put the code in different modules / concerns.

Comment: I don't think close votes are really merited for this question - the question is rather straight forward even if its something thats not entirely possible.

Comment: @Stefan thats not entirely true - the included hook (which is wrapped by ActiveSupport::Concern) takes the class as an argument so you can access any class methods and constants and use that to determine what happens when the method runs. If thats a good idea is somewhat questionable. Where you're correct is that you can't chose what instance methods of a module are included. But this doesn't apply to `scope` as it uses metaprogramming to define a method on the class.

Comment: @Stefan an example of this is `included { |klass| scope ... if klass.do_foo? }`

Comment: @max I meant that you cannot cherry-pick from the outside which parts (or lines) you want to include. You can of course add conditionals and alter the behavior from within the included module. After all, `include` and `included` are just methods.

Answer (score 4):

When including a module you can't actually just include part of the module. All the constants and instance methods of a module are included since the module is added to the ancestors chain of the class.

However the [`Module#included`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Module.html#method-i-included) hook (which is wrapped by [ActiveSupport](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html#method-i-included)) is actually just a plain old method thats passed the class thats its being included in - `self` in the block is also the class. So you can do:

```
module MyConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do |klass|
    if klass::SEACHABLE 
      scope :by_name, ->(name) { where('LOWER(name) like ?', "%#{ name.downcase }%") } 
    end
  end
end

class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  SEARCHABLE = true
  include MyConcern
end


class Bar < ApplicationRecord
  SEARCHABLE = false
  include MyConcern
end
```

It should be noted that `scope` here doesn't actually create a method in the module. Its just using metaprogramming to define a method on the class itself. While you might causually say that its "a scope included in the concern" thats not actually true.

If this is actually a good way to solve your problem is questionable but it can be good to understand whats actually happening underneath the magic.

If you want to provide a degree of customizability to the functionality provided by a module you can write "macro-methods" which is a class method that modifies the class  - `attr_accessor` and the `scope` method are examples of this.

```
module MyConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    def make_searchable(attr)
      method_name = "search_by_#{attr}".intern
      sql = "LOWER(#{attr}) like ?"
      scope method_name, ->(arg) { where(sql, "%#{ arg.downcase }%") }   
    end
  end
end
```

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  include MyConcern
  make_searchable :name
end
```

Here the scope is defined when not when the module is included but when the `make_searchable` method is explicitly called. This pattern lets you pass arguments which is not possible when just including a module.

The drawback is added complexity and that it can hide the method from documentation and code coverage tools.

Comment: thanks @engineersmnky, copypasta got me.